# how to print all date for a month or more

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to print all date from today to specific day this specific day will be taken from database

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_activities where db_id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$day=$row['db_day'];
```

this code give me number of date example 10 days
i want to print date from today to 13 days

```
for($i=1;$i<=$day;$i++){

}
```

output will be like this

```
Thursday 21st of July 2016
Friday 22st of July 2016
       23st of July 2016
       24st of July 2016
       25st of July 2016
       26st of July 2016
       27st of July 2016
       28st of July 2016
       29st of July 2016
       30st of July 2016
       31st of July 2016
       1st of August 2016
```

Comment: You really should include more information..
Do you have any field in your database that represent the date?

Comment: no i take the current date from pc

Comment: you got a date "31st july from db" and you want to print all the dates from 31st july to todays date or todays date to 31st julyr?

Comment: todays to 31st july

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my edited code.

```
$day=$row['db_day'];

$start_day = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$end_day = $start_day + 86400 * $day;

    while($end_day >= $start_day){
            echo date("j F, Y",$start_day)."\r\n";
            $start_day = $start_day + 86400;
    }
```

Comment: how to change $end_day to be dynamic take it from db

Comment: you have used this in your code. just change it to $end_day= strtotime($row['db_day']);

Comment: what are you getting? try doing " echo $row['db_day']; " and let me know what you are seeing.

Comment: i get 15 number of day

Comment: that means.. $row[db_day] is number 15 and not a date. every body over here assumed... it is a date for example "2016-07-22" .

Comment: so you need to print dates from todays date to (todays date + 15 days) ?

Comment: i have added the edited code. please check that and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope its helps

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+9 days')); //add the num of days u need here
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
       echo "<pre>".$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Datetime` class and it's associated methods

```
/* formats for dates */
$df='Y-m-d H:i:s';
$dfo='l jS \of F, Y';

/* variable, number of days from NOW */
$days=14;

/* set the timezone and date interval */
$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$interval=new DateInterval('P1D');

/*establish date range */
$ts=date( $df, strtotime('yesterday') );
$tf=date( $df, strtotime('1st August 2016') );

/* Alternatively... */
$tf=date( $df, strtotime('now +'.$days.' days') );


/* create instances of the `Datetime` class for both dates */
$start=new DateTime( $ts, $timezone );
$end=new DateTime( $tf, $timezone );

/* show the dates in the range */
while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end ){
    echo $start->format( $dfo ). '<br />';
}
```

Will output:

```
Thursday 21st of July, 2016
Friday 22nd of July, 2016
Saturday 23rd of July, 2016
Sunday 24th of July, 2016
Monday 25th of July, 2016
Tuesday 26th of July, 2016
Wednesday 27th of July, 2016
Thursday 28th of July, 2016
Friday 29th of July, 2016
Saturday 30th of July, 2016
Sunday 31st of July, 2016
Monday 1st of August, 2016
Tuesday 2nd of August, 2016
Wednesday 3rd of August, 2016
Thursday 4th of August, 2016
```

Comment: how can i change $tf to be dynamic not static like you make i want to put the varible $day number of day

Comment: made a small amendment above to allow using a variable number of days - taken from NOW ~ ie: 14days, 30days etc

Comment: if you can give me plz an example

Comment: thank you it still one thing it not print 21 of july 2016 how can i solve it